Why am I getting a 256-bit arithmetic error: "unsigined _BitInt of bit sizes greater than 128 not supported" in C++23, Clang-18?
I need to use 256bit arithmetic in my C++ code on Mac with arm processor.
According to this Stack Overflow answer, C++23 has 256-bit arithmetic via _BitInt(256) and it has been implemented in Clang-16. I just installed it through brew install llvm and compiling with clang++ outputs

error: unsigned _BitInt of bit sizes greater than 128 not supported.

Am I doing something wrong or is the answer linked above incorrect? I realize that some of the discussion is about C, but claims are made about C++ as well.

Did you specify C++23 when compiling?

I tried with -std=c++23, but it would still not accept _BitInt(256).

You're misreading the linked question. C23 (ISO/IEC 9899:2024) has _BigInt(256). C++23 (14882:2024) does not. Clang does include it as a Clang-specific extension to C++, but does so even in its C++11 mode.

The post you linked, Is there a 256-bit integer type in C?, is tagged x86-64 and indeed is applicable only to that architecture.  At least up to version 18, clang supports large _Bitint sizes on x86 and x86-64; but on arm and aarch64, they are currently only supported up to 128 bits.  Sorry.
This is not anything specific to the MacOS or homebrew distributions of clang; it also happens for the generic arm/aarch64 compilers used by godbolt.
